# Which versions of fbs, PySide2, shiboken2 and python do you use to distribute Qt for Python project?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside2, fbs

I've tried many different things and for now I'm not sure. Maybe there are some compability errors. The fbs tutorial says that it works with 3.6 v of python and can work with errors on 3.7. But when I'm using 3.6 v of python, import of PySide2 fails. Tried 5.12.0, 5.12.5, 5.13.2 versions of PySide2 with the same of shiboken2. And all i've got was the same:

```
File "C:\Users\test\fbsenv\program_folder\lib\site-packages\shiboken2\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .shiboken2 import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

No matter in venv or not, on different systems with Windows 7(x64). Using 3.7 v of python it works, but I can't freeze my project. Any project, even new empty one, it fails(text of it in the snippet used as spoiler)

```html
(fbsenv) F:\Programming>fbs freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_a
s_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "F:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "F:\Programming\fbsenv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <
module>
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 1
11, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 6
3, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.
py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.
py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", li
ne 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", li
ne 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.
py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", li
ne 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "F:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "F:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Programming\fbsenv\Scripts\fbs-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fbs==0.8.4', 'console_scripts', 'fbs')()
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\fbs\__main__.py", line 17, in _m
ain
    fbs.cmdline.main()
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\fbs\cmdline.py", line 32, in mai
n
    fn(*args)
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\fbs\builtin_commands\__init__.py
", line 120, in freeze
    freeze_windows(debug=debug)
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\fbs\freeze\windows.py", line 18,
 in freeze_windows
    run_pyinstaller(args, debug)
  File "f:\programming\fbsenv\lib\site-packages\fbs\freeze\__init__.py", line 47
, in run_pyinstaller
    run(args, check=True)
  File "F:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pyinstaller', '--name', 'Namer', '--no
upx', '--log-level', 'ERROR', '--noconfirm', '--windowed', '--icon', 'F:\\Progra
mming\\src\\main\\icons\\Icon.ico', '--distpath', 'F:\\Programming\\target', '--
specpath', 'F:\\Programming\\target\\PyInstaller', '--workpath', 'F:\\Programmin
g\\target\\PyInstaller', '--additional-hooks-dir', 'f:\\programming\\fbsenv\\lib
\\site-packages\\fbs\\freeze\\hooks', '--runtime-hook', 'F:\\Programming\\target
\\PyInstaller\\fbs_pyinstaller_hook.py', 'F:\\Programming\\src\\main\\python\\ma
in.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

in 
"F:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 487 there is

```html
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        try:
            stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutExpired:
            process.kill()
            stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
            raise TimeoutExpired(process.args, timeout, output=stdout,
                                 stderr=stderr)
        except:  # Including KeyboardInterrupt, communicate handled that.
            process.kill()
            # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
            raise
        retcode = process.poll()
        if check and retcode:
            raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
                                     output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
```

The second raise is called in this block, I don't know why.
So maybe I'm using wrong versions of something? Why shiboken2 not working on 3.6? Many pople said, thai fbs'll work with PySide(it runs, yet don't freeze), but maybe I should use PyQt?